# How does Node JS managed global vars as he is single threaded and asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, global

I am trying to developpe an API with NodeJs which accepts an object containing multiple queries to mongdb and answers an object with the different results (in fact Json).

I use express and my code is :

```
var nb_query=0;
var results;
//api
app.get("/api/:p",api);
function api(req, res) {
    var jsonq=decodeURIComponent(req.params.p);
    //console.log(jsonq);
    var queries=JSON.parse(jsonq);
    nb_query=Object.keys(queries).length;
    results={};
        for(var nq in queries) { // for each query
            do_find_query(nq,queries[nq], function() {
                //todo : managing head
                res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
                }
            );
        }
 } // end of api function

function do_find_query (name_query,query,callback) {
    var collection=fdb.collection(query.collection);
    collection.find(query.find,query.fields,query.options).toArray(function(err,docs) {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    results[name_query]=docs;
                    nb_query--;
                    if(nb_query==0)
                        callback();
                }
            );

}
```

As you see, I use global vars to store the results and the counter nb_query. And I ask myself if it is a problem or not (now no because I am alone on the server, but when we will be thousands of billions? :-) ).

As I understand Node, there is only one thread and I think Node will finalize a started job unless he encoutered an io access. In this case, he stacks the io with the callback, and begins to answer to a new request.

If this is correct, I think that Node could answer to 2 or more different calls to my api (which need mongo calls) and so store different values in global vars which is shared (there's only one thread).

If this is right, I would also know what is the best way to change it.
I have the idea of declaring results and nb_query in api function and pass it to do_find_query, but nb_query isn't an object and is so not changed correctly.

I know I can put nb_query in an object to pass it 'by reference', but I want to know first if it is necessary and if it is a good way or if there is a better one.

Thanks for your help !

Doom.

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EDIT : 
I have change my code and it seems to work without global vars and without async library (which is for me using a hammer to swat a fly)

```
//api
app.get("/api/:p",api);
function api(req, res) {
    var jsonq=decodeURIComponent(req.params.p);
    //console.log(jsonq);
    var queries=JSON.parse(jsonq);
    var query_names=Object.keys(queries);
    var results={};
    var query_left=query_names.length;
    query_names.map( function(query_name) {
            var query=queries[query_name];
            var collection=fdb.collection(query.collection);
            collection.find(query.find,query.fields,query.options).toArray(function(err,docs) {
                    if(err) throw err; //todo : handle errors in a better way
                    results[query_name]=docs;
                    if(--query_left==0)
                        res.json(results);
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

**But I still do not know if this is necessary to do or not.** (I think so but I am new in Node so ...)

Thanks to mscdex as his answer make me known `res.json()` and help me understand scope of variable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using globals, try this (uses the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module):

```
var async = require('async');

// ...

app.get('/api/:p', api);
function api(req, res) {
  var jsonq = decodeURIComponent(req.params.p),
      queries = JSON.parse(jsonq),
      keys = Object.keys(queries),
      queriesLeft = keys.length,
      results = {};

  async.each(keys, function(name, cb) {
    var query = queries[name],
        collection = fdb.collection(query.collection);
    collection.find(query.find, query.fields, query.options)
              .toArray(function(err, docs) {
                if (err) return cb(err);
                results[name] = docs;
                cb();
              }
    );
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err; // TODO: handle better
    res.json(results);
  });
} // end of api function
```